# Questions about the main debates between Sunnah And Shi'ah

Tags: discussion, scope, sunnah

Lately, A lot of question been asked and these questions actually are not real questions in my opinion which is based on the golden SE rule **(Real questions have Real answers)**. These question did not, do not and will not have real answers! its been debates between Sunnah and Shi'ah since more than a thousand years. Do you think it will be answered now.. I think not.

I am little confused here, Am I understanding the rules regarding this correctly or not? if not then please let me know. If I am correct then what should we do? should we allow questions that clearly ask about unsolved debates between Sunnah and Shi'ah or not? and what actions should be taken? Close Vote or Down Vote?

Your advice is highly appreciated..

Comment: I think it would be good to include links to a few examples.

Answer (score 3):

Quite clearly, such questions should be permitted.  One of the purposes of this site is to allow those who are new to Islam to find answers to their questions.  If such a person asks a question here, they may not know

- that the question is controversial,
- that different sects have different answers for the question.

So, the only sensible thing is to allow such questions; but to ask people who are answering them to flag their responses as sect-specific, if it's appropriate to do so.  The best sort of answer to such a question would be an answer that says "Sect ??? believes ??? and sect ??? believes ???".

Hopefully, if people can submit answers of that form, there won't be arguments along the lines of "my sect is right and your sect is wrong".

Comment: "they may not know: that the question is...." ok thats nice. But I believe this is the reason why SE add the Downvote button and the close vote and comments.. Flag or Downvote, then comment saying `thats a controversial question please ask somewhere else`. Not knowing the the rues is not a good reason for allowing this in my opinion :)

Comment: @HaLaBi I believe you are mistaken. If you hover your mouse over the "downvote" button next to a question, you'll see that this should be done if the question "does not show any research effort, is unclear or not useful".  If you hover your mouse over the "flag" link, you'll see that this is for serious problems or moderator attention.  A question that has no uncontroversial answer does not fit either of those categories. Such a question deserves neither a downvote nor a close. But any answer to such a question should be labelled to indicate which sect's point of view it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Asking questions about these issues is fine in my opinion. For example, you yourself have asked an OK question on the topic of such disputes.

A question like "Was [Muawiyah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muawiyah_I) a just ruler?" a **real** question. Having an answer doesn't mean that all experts on the topic have to agree on the answer. The view of each school of though or sect is *a* valid and real answer to the question.

What we don't want is when a real question turns into a debate in answers/comments which is a non-constructive behavior. The tone of the question is also important here. Stating a sect's beliefs in the question without making explicit that they belong to that sect and are not shared views among Muslims can lead to debate and non-constructive behavior. The best way to deal with these cases is that if you feel there is the possibility of helping the OP to improve the question then politely do it. Usually it is possible to remove the non-constructive content/tone while preserving the question. If the user is a repeated offender or insists on keeping the non-constructive content then follow the suggestions in [Why Sectarianism is Ruining Your Site](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/why-sectarianism-is-ruining-your-site).