# Should we close boring/trivial questions?

Tags: discussion

Quoting from [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/284/44)

> Close boring, trivial, mindless, uninteresting, etc. questions.
>
> It's taken me a long time to get here, but your really need to shut
> down any question that wastes your top-users time and energy. Flag
> these questions. Vote to close when you get the privilege. Comment.
> Vote down as appropriate. Don't forget that you can always edit and
> reopen a question, but you can't refund the time and energy users
> spend answering unfocused questions or arguing about unsupported
> answers.

I think this should be discussed. Should we really close trivial questions? What ifit is a good fit for QA format? And since when a question is trivial, so will its answer and won't take much time of a top-user. And lastly, how do we decide if a question is trivial or not?

Comment: obligatory blog link: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

Answer (score 7):

The goal of Stack Exchange is to make the Internet better and become an expert resource of knowledge for years to come. A beta Stack Exchange site is in a critical phase where the types of questions asked can set the tone of the site for a long time.

**Sacrificing quality poisons the site:**

Remember, Stack Exchange has gone through this same public beta process with countless Q&A sites on every topic imaginable. When quality is sacrificed, the results are always the same. The experts disappear, looking for better communities where they can feel challenged. In the worst cases, the community becomes so filled with useless information, already available in every other corner of the Internet, that people lose their passion for the site and vanish  altogether.

I'm not an expert on Islam, but I have spent enough time on Stack Exchange beta sites to tell you that leaving poor quality questions on your site *will definitely* poison it.

**Welcome and embrace beginners:**

With that said, I want to emphasize that there is a difference between a good question asked by a beginner and a poor quality question:  Just because I am new to Islam doesn't mean I can't go read the Quran and ask a meaningful question about a concept I don't understand.

Welcome beginners. Welcome people who want to learn, but comment, downvote, and flag or close any questions asked by those who waste your time by not putting forth effort. Learning involves effort by two parties, both teacher *and* student. Your site will be much better as a result, and your community will be stronger.