# What do you think about "Why must there be a God?" question?

Tags: discussion

Although I have answered it too, I started have doubts about [Why must there be a God?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1907/why-must-there-be-a-god) question. My objections are

1. Question is too broad
2. No one really knows for sure.

FAQ says that:

> If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re
>   asking too much.

And [here](http://www.mikearobinson.com/) you can find some of the books trying to tackle this subject.

This subject is too argumentative in my opinion. As you can see on that question, validity of answers are being *discussed* below almost every answer, but this is not a discussion forum, but a QA site.

In [Why Sectarianism is Ruining Your Site](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/why-sectarianism-is-ruining-your-site) discussion [aarthi](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8/aarthi) said that;

> The conflicts we see here are reflections of disagreements that
>   stretch back to the seventh century. 1400 years of conflict is not
>   going to be solved on a Stack Exchange site.

How is the question of "Why must God exist" should be any different. Questioning the existence of God goes way back than the topic of that discussion.

Therefore, I think we should close the question as

> **not constructive** As it currently stands, this question is not a good
>   fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts,
>   references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely
>   solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you
>   feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the
>   FAQ for guidance.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an interesting question in there, but would agree that it's too broad, because of the different variations of answers you get. Then again, a lot of the answers to such a question are going to be defensive and not very objective.