# sectarianism and "peaceful questions about disagreements" are the same or different?

Tags: discussion, faq-content

sometimes I am accused to sectarianism by moderators.

I think this site needs a clear definition of sectarianism to this word can not be abused to oppress the users who disagree moderators. (with respect to all current moderators but this is a general question and not directed to any specific moderator)

there are peaceful questions about disagreements among different sects. for example one sect says all shrines should be destroyed and one says they should not be destroyed. how questions should be asked to not be sectarianism?

I think this site needs a clear definition of sectarianism at FAQ and not in form of a meta question with different views on posts that only posts in favor of a view be used among them to take action.

Comment: Difference is mostly in tone. If it sounds offensive/confrontational, it's not peaceful. I don't think it's possible to have a clear guideline on it.

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia defines sectarianism as "bigotry, discrimination or hatred arising from attaching importance to perceived differences between subdivisions within a group, such as between different denominations of a religion, class, regional or factions of a political movement."

However, a clear definition of sectarianism isn't really required.  We the mods — and the community in general — don't crack down on sectarianism *because* it's sectarian. We crack down on it because sectarianism is [inevitably non-constructive and/or offensive](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/why-sectarianism-is-ruining-your-site?rq=1). We're trying build a repository of high-quality questions and answers here, not trying to air out fourteen hundred years of dirty laundry.

As one oft-quoted section of [the FAQ](https://islam.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette) already says:

> Be nice.
>
> Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you. We’re
>   all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may not know
>   everything you know. Bring your sense of humor.

That said, if a post is written in a manner that *respects* (whether or not it actually *agrees with*) the opinions of the entire community, it is pretty much by definition *not* sectarian.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is couple of different points that must be considered while asking about opinions on specific sect;

**Tone of the language:**

Just like any other question, it is really important to use correct language while asking these questions. If questions are asked in a rude or offensive manner, it will not be well received by the community. Such questions would either be edited, or if they are not salvageable through editing, would be deleted. Questions should look like interested in learning a particular sect's point of view on the subject rather than looking like attacking a particular sect. For example, ".... sect did something bad, how do you explain yourself?" looks offensive to me, it could be asked like this instead "What is ruling on this?" and say that you are interested in point of view of a particular sect.

**Constructive:** If it is likely that question would solicit debate, arguments and extended discussion, this is not the place of such questions. [Real questions have answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers). Also, rants disguised in a question like "a particular sect is wrong about this, am I right?" are non-constructive, and should be deleted or closed.

**To the point** Questions should be to the point, and shouldn't include irrelevant hints or political statements embedded in them. For example, [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/how-should-insults-to-the-prophet-muhammad-pbuh-be-handled), although isn't about a particular sect, included a belief statement that didn't contribute to the question itself. Later, it has been removed from the question, and now question looks more focused on actual question.

I want to end this post, by giving an example of your kind of controversial https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2534/what-is-the-justification-of-salafi-scholars-for-destroying-shrine-of-imam-sadiq question. Although question itself is valid, title looks accusing and is a "How do you explain yourself!" type of language. Also, question body itself contains couple of irrelevant statements. If I was going to ask it, I would go with something like this;

---

**Ruling of destruction of holy shrines?**

What is the ruling on destroying shrines of holy people, and how does the ruling different for Prophet (pbuh) and other important religious figures? Note that although [Al-Baqi'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Baqi%27) has been destroyed, shrine of Prophet (pbuh) has not. I am interested in [insert a sect here] point of view.

---

As you can see, using correct language and attitude, you can ask anything about Islam. But if you use accusing language and irrelevant political statements inside your question, it would be problematic and will be recieved badly.

Comment: thanks. InshaAllah I use your guides. its amazing when this form of questions against shia is used (for example http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/how-do-shiites-justify-matam-self-flagellation-and-tatbir-striking-oneself-w) no one in this site oppose it. but it is enough one shia use the word wahhabi.

Comment: @Ahmadi - if you do see an anti-Shia (or anti-anything really) question that isn't following the guidelines, then please report it immediately.

Comment: @SystemDown OK thanks. what about anti Satan? :)

Answer (score 2):

> sectarianism and “peaceful questions about disagreements” are the same
>   or different?

They are different

> I think this site needs a clear definition of sectarianism

I don't know How to define it .But it arises when some one posting without respecting other sects, This is a Question Answer site ,not a discussion  website

> I think this site needs a clear definition of sectarianism at FAQ and
>   not in form of a meta question with different views on posts that only
>   posts in favor of a view be used among them to take action.

I agree with this . But it is difficult