# Possible forms of Sectarianism and biased activity

Tags: discussion, sectarianism

At the early days I joint this site, I tried to post questions supporting my own view of Islam. After a while I found simple obvious tricks to make the judgement of someone reading the post what I liked to be.

Soon when one of moderators commented [this great question on meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/why-sectarianism-is-ruining-your-site) under one of my posts, I found my behavior was neither fair, nor Islamic.

Here I want to list some behaviors that can shape Islam.SE a biased website of negative arguments between different views of Islam, if they are not prevented:

- **I ask the ideas of the opposite sect about some problem, but finally mark the answer posted by a user of my own sect as accepted answer to show opposite is wrong**.
- **I ask some question about opposite sect, wait a few days, and then post the answer I had earlier in my mind**. The users of the other sect that have put their time to answer the question feel they have been cheated, because the question was not a real one, it was just a  creative two-step scenario.
- Some question raises a debate between the ideas of different sects. **Debates here might appear democratic and fair because up/downvoting system, but actually they are not!** If I ask the question, I can select some answer of my sect in a biased way and the people who have a quick look later on the question are more likely to read just the accepted answer.
- I ask: **Are Muslims of the opposite sect Mushrik or Kafir because of this and this?**. The users of the opposite view provide fair referenced answers to prove they are not simply Mushrik or Kafir. But another user answers: **"Yes, they are"** or with poor reasons, and I accept this last answer.

Can you list other behavior of the same manner? Do you agree behaving like this is an example of sectarianism and should be prevented? How we should prevent sectarianism on this website?

Comment: You can never prevent it fully. It's an ongoing battle. And to some degree, you shouldn't care; post your view, and let readers vote for what they think is the most correct, best, or right answer.

Comment: There is a relevant discussion on Christianity.SE which attempts to address some of the inherent bias in accepted answers; only tangentially related, but still worth a look: http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1401/2111

Comment: @ashes999 No tolerance to intolerance. http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/239/no-tolerance-for-intolerance

Comment: @Ali I lived through this experience and I know what I'm talking about. Believe me when I say what I say: you shouldn't care (to some degree, because it's unavoidable). Speak the truth (as you see it), and let people do whatever they want with that. Don't take it personally.

Comment: @ashes999 I fully trust moderators because of their experiences

Comment: I feel a lot of the problems you're listing are also resolved by conscientious voting.