# Why is this question closed

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10054/what-does-it-mean-by-mushrikeen-among-this-ummah-worse-than-the-meccan-mushrike) is a  clear question which asks the ramifications of the quoted statement , it is further explained in the last paragraph that what it means :

> The above two arguments conclude that the Shirk of the erstwhile
>   Meccan pagans was lighter compared to the Modern Mushrikeen (like
>   people who invoke other than Allah for help, goto Shrines etc), So My
>   question is should such Mushrikeen who declare the "Shahada" be only
>   treated as just "sinning Muslims" or they should they be treated as
>   how the Sahaba and prophet treated the erstwhile pagans who also
>   believed in Allah?

The block quote gave the motivation behind asking the question , the question is clear and answerable as [demonstrated](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/10065/940).

Answer (score 2):

I critically read it three times in full, and still couldn't figure out what you were asking.  I never once got the impression that you were asking for "the ramifications of the quoted statement," rather it looked like you were asking for an *interpretation* of the quoted statement, and then changed tack halfway through and started asking about how to treat *mushrikeen* in general.

The fact that the quoted statement was nowhere in the blockquoted text (and according to Google, you're the only person to say that particular statement ever) just confused the matter more.  No attempt was made to emphasize what was important in the block, which meant other users would need to read through — and past — the entire thing to understand that it wasn't even relevant to what the question appeared to ask (an interpretation) in the first place.  Rather, by the end of the question, it appeared that you knew *exactly* what the passage meant.

And then your second question, about how we should treat the *mushrikeen*, is baseless.  The bulk of the question body merely argues that modern *mushrikeen* are, in fact, *mushrikeen*, but it doesn't say anything about how, or why, they should be treated any different from other *mushrikeen*, or why you believe they should.

There is no indication that it, as you claim, "gave the motivation behind asking the question."

Given that your opening question is confusing, the question body is hard to read and apparently irrelevant, and your second question is apparently baseless, I chose to close it as "unclear what you are asking."  I could not see what, if anything, you were expecting in the way of a useful answer.

Just because the question is clear *to you* is irrelevant; you're the one asking the question, obviously *you* understand what you're asking.  What's important is that you communicate that clearly enough that other people can understand what you're asking so they can answer constructively.

The fact that your self-answer mostly just seemed to confirm — and quote the conclusion of — the same essay (rather than discuss the ramifications of it) didn't help matters at all.

---

That said, even if the question was "a clear question which asks the ramifications of the quoted statement," as you claim, it would still have been closed as either "primarily opinion-based" or "too broad."  Questions are expected to be answered according to facts, references, or specific expertise; questions asking for speculation are not, nor have ever been, a good fit for the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Thanks that was a clear explanation can you suggest how to improve it.? Should ask aanother question on tips to make it openable?

Comment: @Islam Based on your above explanation, I don't see any way it can be redeemed.  It is simply not a good fit for SE.

Answer (score 1):

That you answered your own question is hardly evidence that "the question is clear and answerable".

These comments give me pause:

> please clear how prophet SAWW treated the erstwhile pagans who also believed in Allah? also please clear who do you mean exactly by "modern Mushrikeen"? do you mean Shia Muslims or not? if yes then calling Shia Muslims as Mushrik is Takfir that is against teachings of Islam. some corrupted scholars use Takfir to a dictator can kill his protesters easier. – Ahmadi 2 days ago edit

and:

> Its not about shia but a general question applicable to Sufis too. E.g sufis invoke gaus. Al madad where gaus. Is a famous saint Abdul qadir jelani – Islam 2 days ago

In the early days of this site, [sectarianism threatened to ruin it](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/why-sectarianism-is-ruining-your-site).  At first glance, the question and answer look more like extended rants.  After looking up the terms that I was unfamiliar with, it's definitely an attack on the theology and practice of other Muslim groups.  The question was not asked to invite answers from others, but to provide a platform for you to condemn the practices and beliefs of other people.  Besides being uncivil, it violates an important principle for peace on this site:

> For the purpose of this site, **assume that each sect's hadith are valid, and that each sect's accepted imams are reliable.**

(Incidentally, I know enough about the subject to note the reference to "Shaikh Muhammad ibn Abdul Wahhab", who is about as divisive a figure as you could find.)

Comment: My post did not violate the principle you quoted. I never said that a hadith is invalid etc. In fact I quoted popular hadith Quran and sayings of the Shaikh who is as popular as how any other imam is.

Comment: Moreover I did not take the name of any sects. I made the question as generic as possible it was in the comments that Ahmad introduced his sect.

Comment: @Islam: I might not know much, but I can tell that "modern Mushrikeen" is a pejorative term.  In other words, you'd probably not like it if I claimed that you and your system of belief fell under that category.  By labeling not just non-Muslims (such as myself) but even other Muslims with this term, you are sowing the seeds of discord on the site.  While it's possible to ask about, say, patrons in a respectful manner, that is not what you've done.  ["That which you want for yourself, seek for mankind."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Rule#Islam)