# Why was the islamic law related question put on hold?

Tags: discussion

I am getting following message in the question https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17330/is-isis-performing-under-islamic-rules:

> put on hold as off-topic by goto, goldPseudo♦ 16 hours ago

I dont think this is a political question but a question which asks about the validity of the actions of ISIS , it is like asking "XYZ" is doing "ABC" and is "ABC" allowed by the sharia under the condition  of war?

Clearly this is not a political question. Hence please let me know what edits are required to open the question.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are doing the right thing by bringing this up here on meta - that is the constructive way of allowing the community to speak up and to address a bad decision if there has been one - so you have my +1 to say "thanks for bringing this up in the right place and the right way" but *not* to say "I agree with you".

So, why don't I agree?

- Because the question [is political](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/political):

  > Of, relating to, or dealing with the structure or affairs of government, politics, or the **state**.
- Because although by the measure of community approval some carefully worded political questions [might be on-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/996/3208),

  > Political questions are likely to be controversial and lead to lengthy and extended debate and discussion. They need be stated very carefully to avoid such issues. They need considerable care to be stated reasonably.

  I can't see any evidence (even in the latest revision of the question) that suggests care has been taken to avoid provoking lengthy and extended debate and discussion.
- Because if this question wasn't off-topic, it'd still be far too broad:

  > ...Do they do what they do..."

  unless that is made a lot more specific, how can an answer possibly address everything 'they' do without writing a whole book? OK, I'm not exactly disagreeing with you here, because you never said it isn't too broad, but if the question is junk anyway arguing whether it is on-topic is going to seem pointless to many. In other words, if you want to make the case for a political question being on-topic, you'd be better served by picking or writing one that is otherwise good.
- Because if it wasn't off-topic and too broad, it'd still be primarily opinion-based.

  > "is there any authentic narration"

  Who gets to define what is 'authentic' on this site? that's just opinion-bait, and at the very least should be carefully re-phrased.

Last but not least, it's obvious you put considerable effort into your answer. I don't think it's a 'good' answer because it's polemical and soap-box style, but if you were to put that much effort into answering in a way that fits this site and the SE model of Q&A, you'd pretty soon be a top user here. I hate seeing effort go to waste and I hope it may be some small encouragement that it inspired [my third ever contribution on I.SE](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17347/3208).

Comment: Just a PS to note that I am not Muslim - but I am interested in this site and would like it to succeed: I'd like a healthy thriving community to which I can pose questions about how to approach and understand the Quran on its own terms.

Comment: The  question is not about the political state but the actions it is doing , I have clearly differentiated in the question itself: "is the action "ABC" allowed by the sharia under the condition of war?"

Comment: The 'actions it is doing' [is still politics](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/politics) - but that's not really the point which is that the health of the site depends on it not descending into a contentious cess-pool of heated opinions and counter-opinions - precisely the kind that controversial contemporary events are likely to provoke. Give it 100 years of perspective and then questions about ISIS might get a calm answer.

Comment: well then all prophets were also political, does that mean we stop asking questions about the prophet pbuh?

Comment: anyways I have changed the question to : OK changed to: Is it possible for a Islamic organisation engaged in Jihad to reconcile with the western society [on hold], In Islam Jihad has been fought since the time of the early companions. Recently a caliphate has been declared on the lines of the early companions, which the world percieves as unjust and wrong due to media propoganda,Hence are there any authentic narration(s) that asks Muslims to wage a Jihad against the Infidels till the day of Judgement ? –

Answer (score 2):

The close reason given is rather clear:

> "Questions on politics are off-topic as they're rarely productive or relevant to the teachings of Islam."

That question, as written, has already attracted two answers; one of which was flagged for being offensive and deleted, and the other (yours) which is naught more than blatant apologism (which is [not what this site is for](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22)).

This is a pattern that is consistent with questions of this nature: They will almost inevitably attract partisan answers, apologetic answers which agree and polemic answers which disagree.  Voting thereupon just becomes a popularity contest, which does *nothing* to forward the academic study of Islam.

It does, however, breed exactly the sort of [sectarianism](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/275/22) which has plagued this site from the beginning.

We are not a forum.  We are not a site for argument or debate.  We are not a site to prove other people right or wrong.  We are not a soapbox for personal views. We are a site for clear, focused questions about the topic of Islam, which can be effectively and constructively answered according to the mechanics of the Stack Exchange model.

That question is not one of these.

Comment: "is "ABC" allowed by the sharia under the condition of war?"a  valid question ?

Comment: @Ahlelbayt According to who?  There's more than one interpretation of the Shariah.  And I don't see how it's relevant to this topic, since the question you linked isn't asking about any particular "ABC" at all, it's asking about all everything ISIS does ever which pretty much throws it under the "Too Broad" bus anyway.

Comment: OK changed to: Is it possible for a Islamic organisation engaged in Jihad to reconcile with the western society [on hold],
 In Islam Jihad has been fought since the time of the early companions. Recently a caliphate has been declared on the lines of the early companions, which the world percieves as unjust and wrong due to media propoganda,Hence are there any authentic narration(s) that asks Muslims to wage a Jihad against the Infidels till the day of Judgement ?

Comment: @Ahlelbayt Besides the fact that that premise has nothing to do with the actual question asked, it *fundamentally* changes what the *actual questioner* was asking.  And as written is still more likely to attract *exactly* the same sort of polemic and apologetic answers than anything constructive.

Comment: but I see a lot of appologetical questions \answers on this site like questions about tawwasol,shia-sunni disputes , earlier I saw front page full of such questions. Shia sunni itself is political so why is that allowed?

Comment: @Ahlelbayt Again, irrelevant to this topic.  I've already answered why *this particular question* was closed; if you want to ask about a *completely different topic* bring up a new meta discussion.

Comment: @Ahlebayt, 1. The fact that there are inappropriate questions that are not closed yet does not mean the new ones should not be. When requesting a reopening of a closed question "Why such and such question is not closed" never works. 2. Early history of Islam does not fall under _recent_ political topics. Neither does issues that Shia and Sunni disagree upon. So the rule does not apply to them if they are appropriately stated. 3. I think in principle you can rephrase such questions in a way that are about Islam and not recent political events. However it is a quite difficult task.

Comment: [Cont.] I personally don't see any way of salvaging a suitable question from this one. It seems mainly an expression of unhappiness and a request for confirmation that ISIS does not represent Islam than a question about Islam. If the author was more specific and mentioned a particular action then it _might_ be possible to state a question asking something like "did the prophet do X?". But the author does not and just asks completely  generally that ISIS doesn't represent Islam. You can't do much with a question like that.