# Arbitrary decisions again by a moderator

Tags: discussion, moderation

First of all the topic I was banned for was related to the tragedy in Mena, a topic significant enough on its own to invoke the sympathy and interest of any muslim.

The cause of the tragedy is still debated in [the mainstream media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainstream_media), but the already known facts surrounding the incident and the kind of response and performance by Saudis towards this catastrophe provide strong ground for suspicion and I am personally almost convinced, as [this Western journalist extensively argues](http://82.221.129.208/ag8index.html), that this was a Mossad operation to kidnap Iranian high-ranking officials.

Last night, I was deeply moved by the implications of this conspiracy, and felt sharing this with some muslim friends here. Of course, one may not agree with my opinion, but that could be up for a discussion. But a moderator proceeding to ban a user for simply posting an opinion and two links in regards with an incident concerning Islam and muslims, is to me just the old story of a reckless moderator who still seems to think that iron-fist measures contribute anything to creating a positive atmosphere in this site!

I know what his typical counter-arguments might be, but again those are no justification for a moderator who thinks he can compensate lack of sympathy and good-faith with the cold technicalities. My posts were removed and I was banned for no trouble or unease caused except apparently for the personal sensitivity of a moderator.

Comment: I sympathise with your feeling: Mena is a tragedy; however the internet is a breeding ground of rumour and conspiracy theories; it's doesn't seem useful to fan those kind of flames ...

Comment: @MoziburUllah, And that's the argument always used to prevent any serious discussion about the plight of muslims.

Comment: SE isn't optimised for discussion; if you want to write to highlight issues then there are places like [this](https://electronicintifada.net/content/submit-content-electronic-intifada/3) who take a responsible editorial line; you'll also get a much wider readership.

Answer (score 2):

We have decided that these kind of political topics are off-topic here. We don't want this site to turn into a site for political discussions of recent events. First, this is not a discussion site, it is a Q&A site. Second, these topics tend to lead to heated extended discussions which negatively effects the site. Therefore for the time being [questions about contemporary politics are off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/985/) here.

If moderators are intervening through appropriate actions to uphold this policy their actions are justified and expected.

Comment: I know This is an old question. I am answering it so it won't be popped up in future by the community bot, and may serve as a reference for similar questions in future.