# Based on what site policy and by what decision making process the question

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-questions

There has been a meta [discussion here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/898/what-should-be-done-about-question-10819) about what to do about this question:

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10819/is-zionism-the-enemy-of-islam-what-about-the-other-isms

But I am interested to know:

1- Based on what policy accepted by community (not only proposed on meta) this question is deleted. please mention how it has became a policy for specifically Islam site community.

2- how had beed the process for deciding this question should be deleted.

There has been different opinions in related meta discussion. why some of them are ignored and why one of them is selected as administrative action for this question. how is the process?

Edit:
Here is not the place for telling your opinion about the deleted question that if should be deleted or not. but question is clear: what policy of site says that question should be deleted. and how it has became a policy of this site.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best explanation is that the answer given in the Meta discussion that you link to by goldPseudo is essentially the general policy of all of the SE sites. I can't see the deleted questions, but based on their titles I will assume that to answer them requires extensive knowledge of topics outside Islam and little knowledge about Islam.

For example, in order to answer whether Zionism is the enemy of Islam, one would have to have an understanding of the core tenets of Zionism. Once you know those, it should be pretty obvious whether or not Zionism is the enemy of Islam regardless of whether you actually know anything about Islam. Therefore, it's really not a question about Islam at all.  Furthermore, you'd really have to understand the core tenets of the various factions of Zionists because perhaps some of them could be considered enemies of Islam and others not.

A more appropriate question might be: "Could a movement dedicated to populating a Muslim-majority region with non-Muslims in order to gain political control of that region be considered an enemy of Islam?"

An even better question (read: even more related to Islam) could be: "Would Islam condone and/or call for resistance--political and/or military--against a movement dedicated to populating a Muslim-majority region with non-Muslims in order to gain political control of that region?"

Comment: are you sure your post answers the above question? please read the question again. that meta link contains different opinions. question is why one of them is selected as policy. why not another one?

Comment: @BattleofKarbala Because that answer conforms to the SE policy in general, as my first paragraph states.

Comment: can you please add the reference of this general SE policy? I mean an official required term from SE Inc. saying politics is banned in sites of network.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala I didn't say that politics is off-limits. Questions that aren't about the topic of the site are off-limits as should be obvious. As I have shown, these are not questions about Islam; they are about Zionism/Israel. Just because the questioner mentions Islam does not mean that it is a question about Islam. No real knowledge of Islam is required to answer those questions. Only an extensive knowledge of Zionism, which is not the focus of this site.

Comment: I disagree you that question is about Israel. but it is about knowing current enemy of Islam. Indeed Islam has enemies and knowing enemies of Islam is part of knowing Islam which is topic of this site. determining enemy of Islam needs knowledge of Islam. prophet SAWW had near 100 wars by enemies of Islam. he did not fight without knowledge of Islam.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala That is irrelevant to the discussion here. If I ask, "Is xyz the enemy of Islam," you can't answer that question unless you know about xyz. The accepted practice on SE is that we don't assume that SE users have extensive knowledge about topics unrelated to the main topic of the site. It is possible (and potentially good) to ask a question about enemies of Islam on this site, but the relevant information must be provided rather than assuming potential answerers know it. See the example questions in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In full agreement with everything Daniel said in his post, but the real answer is simply: The post had been closed for three months, and was providing zero value to the site.

A meta discussion is only really as useful as its ability to achieve something.  After three months, not only did it fail to demonstrate any clear community opinion either way, it also failed to result in the question being significantly improved, and definitely failed in getting the question *reopened*.

Sure, there may have been a possibility of it being salvaged.  But the fact remains that over three months, nobody cared enough to actually do so.

Comment: zero value is your personal opinion or site policy. please read the question again. how it has became a policy for this site? if it had no clear opinion so based on what policy it was deleted? I think this post does not answer the question. based on what accepted policy by community that answer was deleted? where is that policy? did you answer this in your post?

Comment: @BattleofKarbala You keep asking for some sort of Islam.SE-specific policy, but there is no such thing.  Check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58842/132874 if you want a relevant meta discussion.