# Censorship in Islam Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, moderation, capital-t-truth, curation

I've been answering some questions regarding the death of Jesus (as) with a very detailed lists of proofs as to his death being proven by Quran and Hadith. Yet they are being deleted by moderators (goldPseudo) without explanation. I have put a lot of work into these answers and I am very frustrated by this.

This is a link to the list of proofs which I copied into this google doc.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hiqgKcEo64B70XPkBxMNYXaYTFl6T47qV3XK1-MrtvY/edit?usp=sharing

Regardless of anyone's views on the topic, deleting comments to silence someone is not the way of Islam.

Comment: Complaining about moderator decisions like this on the main site is not the way of Islam.SE. I am doing you the courtesy of migrating this post to meta instead of deleting it outright, but it would behoove you to be forthright about _why_ your posts were deleted (I left comments explaining every deletion) if you actually want a constructive dialog about this.

Comment: hello brother. Sorry If i sound whiny. But I was very frustrated that you deleted the comment on the "is jesus alive or dead." I think the answer I gave there suited the question. Yes, he was asking specifically about Jesus being alive in the description. But I refuted the idea that Jesus is alive through those verses in my answer.

Comment: And afterwards i got a bit excited and started posting everywhere. That I agree, was out of context. Please forgive me for that brother.

Comment: Though now i cannot post an answer to any question. which i think is unfair since now i cannot even make up for my mistake by answering questions sticking to the topic. That's why I felt as though I was being censored. Though now I do understand why – i was being spammy.

Comment: However, i still do feel my answer on Jesus's death was befitting to the topic. so I would like to ask you that how could I change my answer to suit your expections.

Comment: once again, i am not trying to cause enmity of any sort. I just want to voice my beliefs.

Comment: please link to the deleted questions. i would like to see are they still deleted. there are several questions on the topic on the front page now.

Answer (score 4):

Islam.SE is a pluralistic site. This means that we are open to questions and answers regarding *every* interpretation of Islam. One of the [earliest decisions we made](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/275/22) was that we wouldn't allow sectarianism to ruin the site.

Every interpretation of Islam has its followers, and those followers are all convinced that their interpretation is the [capital-t-truth](/questions/tagged/capital-t-truth) and that everyone else is *objectively wrong*. Arguments about which interpretation of Islam is True and which interpretations are accursed heresies have historically ranged anywhere from civil to heated to dangerously violent for fourteen centuries or so, and we don't want none of that *here*: People have been at it for almost as long as Islam has been around, and there's already countless Internet fora out there full of people trying to prove which interpretation is "more correct" and getting nowhere.

We are here to share *knowledge* about the topic of Islam. Censorship is complete anathema to that goal, but good curation is *vital*; knowledge is useless if people can't *find* it. Part of that curation is that users are expected to ask focused questions which makes it clear exactly *what* knowledge they're seeking, and the answerers can *provide* that knowledge, and future visitors can *find* that knowledge because now they know where to look.

The aforementioned Internet fora are terrible at this sort of thing. People ask a question, and they're likely to get multiple different competing answers, often mutually incompatible, from who knows what flavour of Islam. Even well-intentioned, this only serves to further confuse the layman and muddy the waters for people who are actually trying to find information. Instead of gaining knowledge, people just leave with more questions and less understanding. In many cases it drives people with weak *imaan* to abandon the faith completely.

Stack Exchange gets around this by focusing on clear and focused questions, and clear and focused answers. Ideally, this allows knowledge to be easily found and shared, not obfuscated behind arguments and tangential discussions. If someone were to open a question that says, for example, "[Is there anyone here who can prove to me that Jesus is alive in heaven using Quranic quotation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/55239/22)," they should reasonably expect to find Quranic quotations supporting the idea that Jesus is alive, not answers providing exactly the opposite point of view.

We welcome your knowledge, and encourage you to share it with us. You can even share the knowledge you have gained by self-answering your own questions, although how well received such posts will be is entirely up to the community. But we do need to ensure this is a comfortable environment for everyone, regardless of their beliefs, so we cannot afford to be accommodating to posts that push opinions on people who did not ask for them.

Comment: Thank you, now I see your points loud an clear. Sorry for whatever misunderstanding happened between us. I just have a history of getting banned for sharing my views elsewhere (reddit) and thought the same was happening here. I really appreciate you taking the time to write this response so I can understand.